# Windows 7 Credential Provider Sample

Tags: windows-7, credentials, provider

I'm trying to create a custom login for Windows 7 using Credential Provider. I use Windows 7 Professional,  Windows SDK 7.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. After i build the solution for SampleCredentialProvider from 
the sample folder in SDK 7.0 my dll file is created, i copy the dll file into my Windows\System32 folder and i run the Register.reg but nothing is happening at login. According to the documentation in the login screen i should be able to see new users(Administrator and Guest). What have i done wrong? Is there a trick or something?

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask you where found documentation on creating a CP?  Everything I find keeps pointing me back to the same MSDN article, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is also some documentation in the Windows SDK where you can find the sample CP applications.

Comment: The SampleCredentialProviders that is being mentioned above can be downloaded from Microsoft, at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5372

Comment: Actually, this is the FINAL release: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B1B3CBD1-2D3A-4FAC-982F-289F4F4B9300 (earlier link was to the Beta version)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you on Windows 7 64-bit? If so, check to see whether you are building the Win32 version instead. Use the *Build* `>` *Configuration Manager* and make sure *Active solution platform* is **x64**, and the *Active solution configuration* is **Release**.

Comment: If I try to build a 64 bit version (either release or debug) nothing happens.  The thing just doesn't build anything.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) have good Credential Provider samples