# Change the login process for windows 7

Tags: windows, authentication

I am looking into changing the Windows 7 login process for my school project. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any way to do so..

I would like to replace the standard user-name and password with a QR code, graphical password and a kinect motion password. Is there anyway to do this (is it even possible?).

Alternatively I am looking to have an application that will open up full-screen without a close, minimize button etc, and have it open on windows login.

Any code example or reference would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sure there will be some some API to provide this but this is quiete complex. From which programming language are you talking? What have you tried yet?

Comment: Hoping to use c# to do it, unless there is another better language to do so? The project is still in the planning stage so have not tried much yet except looking around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credential Providers are used in Windows 7 to implement custom authentication schemes.  Here are some links that may prove useful:

[Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

[Documentation for creating a Custom Credential Provider in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228499/documentation-for-creating-a-custom-credential-provider-in-windows)

[Windows 7 Credential Provider Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296397/windows-7-credential-provider-sample)

Answer (score 1):

A good read on Windows internals should help you understand what you need for this project. Mark Russinovich is pretty much the man when it comes to Windows internals and has written numerous books on the topic.

- Windows Sysinternals: [Windows Internals Book](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx)
- Amazon: [product page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648735)

Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with Microsoft, Sysinternals, or Amazon.

Comment: Thanks! Read the book and there was one very useful page on Windows Authentication, and credential providers.