# SUGGESTIONS NEEDED - Running a Windows Form Application exe before system logon & store the form details in a database

Tags: winforms

Friends, I have been assigned a final year project like the following -
Before the login windows of Windows appears, my Windows Form App .exe should execute and be displayed.
It should not be possible to navigate from this form i.e. alt + ctrl + del and alt+tab and more commands should be disabled.
Once the values in the form fields are entered and submitted, they must go and get stored in a database on my college server
After all this happens only, the windows logon should appear and the user can then login and use the desktop.

I just know to create Windows Forms to some extent. Can u please suggest me how to do this whole process?

How to start the form on startup before the Windows Login? How to place that data into a database?

I do not know even 10% of Windows Forms , so please give a small description of your suggestions

Comment: Not sure how this is ASP.net. Also hating to point out the obvious, but if this is your final year project should you not have learnt things like how to save data to a database?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: mr jon PPP! for ur knowledge know how to behave. i never told i do not know to save data to a database. my requirement is to allow the windows form not to close until data is submitted. i just mentioned about the database cos it shouldn be confusing. stop it man

Answer (score 2):

To have a form load before login with the navigation requirements you request requires actually changing the login screen to a custom one.

This has been possible in all versions of windows; the Netware client (R.I.P.) used to do this so Windows would authenticate with Netware servers. The method for doing this has changed since Vista and is different than the one used in NT 4.0 - XP.

Here're some links to get you started:

[Change the login process for windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467247/change-the-login-process-for-windows-7)

[Windows Credential Provider with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092696/windows-credential-provider-with-c-sharp)

Saving whatever information is in the form to a database should be straight forward, thought there are some security concerns regarding the connection string.